# BigQuery Credentials in .NET

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, credentials

Is there some way I can use OAuth 2.0 to get credentials for my BigQuery account and use them to upload? I have seen the solution where I set the environment variables, but that is not an option for my code. Is there another way I could go about doing it so that I did not have to provide a credential file or set any environment variable? I have an OAuth 2.0 client ID set up in BigQuery, but I'm not quite sure how to use it for upload in .NET.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use end-user credentials or is a service account okay? My answer is for a service account.

Comment: Either works. I'm going with a service account for now, because that seems easiest.

Comment: I'm now getting an error that my user does not have create permissions in the project.

Comment: You might have to grant your service account the [bigquery.dataEditor IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#roles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to authenticate will be to download a service account JSON key file. See the [guide for getting started with authentication on Google Cloud APIs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) for detailed instructions for creating and downloading service account credentials.

If you cannot set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, you can explicitly load the credentials from the JSON file using [GoogleCredential.FromStream(Stream)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.10.0/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleCredential#a3daca048765c959a4f9c34294f4efe06)

Once you have created a `GoogleCredential`, you can pass it in to the [BigQueryClient.Create(String, GoogleCredential)](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClient.html#Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_BigQueryClient_Create_System_String_Google_Apis_Auth_OAuth2_GoogleCredential_).